# Using kubeconfig contexts simply

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I need to use now multiple cluster, currently what I did is simple put all the kubeconfig
under `.kube` folder and any time update the config file with the cluster which I need , e.g.

`mv config cluserone`
`vi config`
insert new kubeconfig to the `config` file and start working with the new cluster,
Let say inside the `/Users/i033346/.kube` I've all the kubeconfig file one by one.

is there a way to use them as contexts without creating a new file which contain all of them.

I try to use also [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) however when I use:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/Users/i033346/.kube/trial
```

and

```
export KUBECONFIG=/Users/i033346/.kube/prod
```

and use `kubectx` I always get the last one and doenst get list of the defined contexts,any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KUBECONFIG env var supports multiple files, comma-separated:

```
export KUBECONFIG="/Users/i033346/.kube/trial,/Users/i033346/.kube/prod"
```

This should be enough to see all of them in `kubectx`.

You can even merge all configs to 1 file:

```
export KUBECONFIG="/Users/i033346/.kube/trial,/Users/i033346/.kube/prod"
kubectl config view --flatten > ~/.kube/config
```

Comment: Thanks, I may be missing something as when I did `export KUBECONFIG=/Users/i033346/.kube/trial,/Users/i033346/.kube/prod` and run after `kubectx` I get error: `W0831 10:42:42.959625   15947 loader.go:223] Config not found: Users/i033346/.kube/trial,Users/i033346/.kube/prod` , any idea what could be missing?

Comment: Im able to see the(trial/prod) files under the `~/.kube` folder

Answer (score 0):

What I used to do in this scenario is to create multiple aliases pointing to different config files.

e.g

in  your .bashrc/.zshrc

edited `in your ~/.bashrc or your ~/.zshrc`

```
alias k-cluster1="kubectl --kubeconfig /my_path/config_cluster1"
alias k-cluster2="kubectl --kubeconfig /my_path/config_cluster2"
```

after loading the terminal `k-cluster1 get pods` or `k-cluster2 get pods` should work

Comment: Im using mac, I dont find this path , try : `cd ~/.bashrc/.zshrc` got no such file or directory error

Comment: I'm sorry I meant in the ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc files depending on your terminal configuration you can check this for further information about these files 

https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/about-bash_profile-and-bashrc-on-macos/